# Binary inversion

Tags: python, binary

I need the cleanest way to invert a specific bit in a number, where the leftmost bit is the LSB.

For example, if I have a function `invert(n, b)` and I were to execute `invert(15, 0)`, it should invert the zeroth digit from the left. And if I were to execute `invert(15, 1)` it would invert the first digit from the left, etc.

Comment: Could you provide sample input and output?

Comment: I have updated my answer and added your example.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to invert specific bits of a (integer) number, you can use:

```
def flipBit (n, b): #n the number, b the bit, 0 = LSB
    return n ^ (1 << b)
```

If you need a string of this number, use `bin(x)[2:]`.

Example:

```
def flipBit(n, b):
    return n ^ (1 << b)

def toBinStr(n):
    return bin(n)[2:]

y = 42
print('Number is {}.'.format(toBinStr(y)))
for x in range(8):
    print('Flipping bit {} gives {}.'.format (x, toBinStr(flipBit(y, x))))
```

---

Your example:

```
#number that needs inversion
number = '1010'
#bit that needs to be inverted (first digit here)
bit_to_invert = 1

##code here##
inverted = bin(int(number, 2) ^ (1 << (bit_to_invert - 1)))[2:]

#this should output 1011
print inverted
```

Comment: I tried using your flipBit function, and it works great! I also do prefer the integer over the string. The only question I have is how would I make 0 the MSB instead of LSB?

Comment: Do you mean make 1 the LSB and not 0 the LSB? Because this is what you do in your sample I/O? If 0 were the MSB, your example would yield 1110.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally made that unclear. The sample IO should output 0010. I'll correct that in the OP.

Comment: So basically `flip('0100', 1)` is different from `flip('100', 1)`? Or are they of fixed size? Or do you count from the first set bit?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was thinking incorrectly while I was writing the sample. 'flip(1010, 1)' would output 1110. B, in your function, should be the bit being inverted counting from the left.

Comment: What are expected outputs for `flip('011', 0)`, `flip('11', 0)`, and `flip('11111', 1)`?

Comment: You know what? I accidentally brought up all this confusion by reading something incorrectly. Your second comment on this answer is was I want (I am an idiot).

Comment: In this case just subtract `1` from `bit_to_invert` as shown in my last code snippet. Glad to help. And btw, we are all idiots, just with different fields of competence.

Comment: Yes, I think the fact we are all idiots is true. I'll reword my original question entirely so we can start over, because I think we are thinking in two completely different ways (your last snippet doesn't have the output I need).

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved through the modulo operation:

```
reverse_bin[x] = MOD(x+1,2)
```

Comment: Your code produces a `NameError: name 'MOD' is not defined`.  This question expects an answer in Python.